# Вычисление высоты TextBox в зависимости от содержимого

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Как правильно вычислить высоту **TextBox** элемента с конфигурацией `Multiline = true`, `Margin = 3;3;3;3` и текстом не содержащего переноса строк, но при этом ширина зависит от размера родительского элемента, которая в свою очередь зависит от содержимого до **TextBox**?

На данный момент использую такой код в котором пытаюсь учесть автоперенос в зависимости от длины:

```
string[] words = info.getDescription().Split(' ');

int heightIncrement = TextRenderer.MeasureText(info.getDescription(), this.labelDesc.Font).Height;
int fHeight = 0;
int lineWidth = 0;
int maxWidth = this.Width - 6; // Padding before left and right borders form and textbox.

int lines = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    int wordWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(words[i], this.labelDesc.Font).Width;
    if (lineWidth + wordWidth >= maxWidth)
    {
        lineWidth = wordWidth + 3; // Add space size after word.
        fHeight += heightIncrement;
        lines += 1;
        continue;
    }

    lineWidth += wordWidth;

    if (i < words.Length - 1)
        lineWidth += 3; // Add space size after word.
}

this.labelDesc.Width = this.Width - 6;
this.labelDesc.Height = fHeight;
this.labelDesc.Text = info.getDescription();
this.labelDesc.Visible = true;
```

В 50% случаев угадывает. В 40% увеличивает высоту на 1-2 строки. В 10% случаев теряет одну строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён заменой **TextBox** на **Label** с управлением максимально допустимой шириной **Label** в зависимости от текущей ширины формы. В таком случае **AutoSize** родительского элемента работает адекватно.